# I am trying to fetch random images of cats from public-apis to my index.html (picture does not load)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

It seems to kinda work, but it won't load the picture

```
let element2 = document.getElementById("button3"); 
element2.addEventListener("click", () => {
let cat_result = document.getElementById("cat_result");
fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
cat_result.innerHTML = '<img src="${data.file}"/>'
    })
```

});

Comment: Change ```'<img src="${data.file}"/>'``` to `\``<img src=${data.file} />`\`` .. Replace single quote with backtick .. Working example: codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/KKXBRpY

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<img src="" id="cat_result"/>
```

I believe, your html image tag like this. You can use setAttribute instead of innerHTML.

Js

```
let element2 = document.getElementById("button3"); 
element2.addEventListener("click", () => {
let cat_result = document.getElementById("cat_result");
fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
cat_result.setAttribute('src', data.file);
})
```

Hope, it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Template literals need to have backticks (``) around them. More about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let element2 = document.getElementById("button3"); 
element2.addEventListener("click", () => {
let cat_result = document.getElementById("cat_result");
fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
cat_result.innerHTML = `<img src="${data.file}"/>`
    })
});
```

```html
<button id="button3">click</button>
<div id="cat_result"></div>
```

Comment: ```"${data.file}"```, Here the double quote is unnecessary.